# Flutter - I want to detect if any URL is entered in the TextField and want to display the preview of the URL on the go if entered

Tags: flutter, dart

If a user has entered any URL while typing the description in the textfield and I want that url to be detected and want a preview of that URL displayed as well.

Does anyone have some ideas on how that can be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

You can listen to the `TextEditingController` to detect it when it's printed, in my example, I will recognize the URL that contains "http" text :

in `StatefulWidget`:

```
 late TextEditingController _controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _controller = TextEditingController();
    _controller.addListener(() {
      if (_controller.text.contains("http")) {
        print("link detected :");
        print(_controller.text.split(' ').firstWhere(
              (element) => element.startsWith("http"),
            ));
      }
    });
    super.initState();
  }
```

The `TextField` widget:

```
TextField(
      controller: _controller, // assign that controller
    );
```

after a hot restart, when your type in the `TextField`, if some text starts with the "http" ( which is the URL) the listener will print it.

you can use it to achieve your goal.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [anylink](https://pub.dev/packages/any_link_preview) package :

```
on TextField(
  onChange: (url){
    bool isValidUrl = AnyLinkPreview.isValidLink(
      url,
      protocols: ['http', 'https'],
      hostWhitelist: ['https://youtube.com/'],
      hostBlacklist: ['https://facebook.com/'],
    );
   if(isValidUrl){
     setState((){
      _currentUrl = url;
   })

}
  }
) 



AnyLinkPreview(
...
   link: _currentUrl,
..
```